# Как правильно написать заголовок документа

Tags: орфография

Действие работников охраны при невозможности РАБОТНИКА(-ОМ) из состава ДС, вооруженного служебным оружием, исполнять должностные обязанности по состоянию здоровья.

Comment: Я почитал ответы, понял, что смысл до непосвященного не доходит. Охрана и ДС - это одно и то же?

Comment: ДС - дежурная смена. Вопрос в окончании слова РАБОТНИКА

Comment: На ваш вопрос я ответил. ***У вас - "вооруженного ...", значит работника.***  А у меня вопрос - не в окончании. ДС и охрана - одно и  то же? Если да то, канцелярщина просто зашкаливает. И в таком случае, действительно, стоит сказать "сотрудника".

Comment: Не заголовок «как написать», а название. И не о нём вопрос, а только о склонении слова в этой путанной череде слов, усиленной «ДС». Править вопрос — без пользы, закрывать поздно. Оставить в назидание...

Answer (score 1):

Ой, одна фраза, а столько канцелярщины наворочено ((((. 
Попроще никак нельзя?

Ну попробую ответить.

Если коротко.
У вас - "вооруженного ...", значит **работника**.
Было бы "работником" - потребовало бы "вооруженным...". 
Не находите? Остальное все не столь критично.

Если подробно.
С учетом сказанного, грамматически допустимы оба варианта.
Исполнение обязанности - кем? - *вооруженным работником*.
Обязанности - кого? (чьи?) - *вооруженного работника*.

Мне ближе вариант "работником", поскольку по смыслу главное слово - "исполнение", но это субъективно.

Другое дело, что формулировка настолько запутанная - на грани косноязычия, - что очевидно нуждается в правке помимо сути вопроса.

Вот это, пожалуй, лучше, хотя тоже "не торт".

***Действие работников охраны при невозможности вооруженного служебным
оружием работника из состава ДС исполнять должностные обязанности по
состоянию здоровья***

Здесь вариант "работника" лучше, два нанизанных творительных (работником - каким? - "вооруженным" - чем? - "оружием") плохо воспринимается.

В отношении "работник" vs "сотрудник". Спорный момент. С точки зрения правовых взаимоотношений в рамках выполнения служебных обязанностей - да, они сотрудники. Но по трудовому кодексу - работники. Здесь можно и так и так трактовать. Посмотрите, как вообще принято в данной конкретной охранной конторе.

Answer (score 0):

Обязанности вооружённого сотрудника охраны ДС с ограниченными по здоровью возможностями.

Comment: С ограничениями по здоровью в ДС не берут ))). Тут вообще непонятно, Охрана - это же не ДС получается? Некая охранная контора, вызвавшая ДС - дорожную или диспетчерскую службу.